# What is the significance of this icon?

Tags: the-long-dark

So the game features an ultra minimalistic interface, but while most of the things I've seen so far made sense, I cannot figure out what exactly is that icon (and the following percentage) representing:

[image: unknown symbol]

Is it Health? Is it Warmth? Is it my sugar level? What is the consequence in the game if it drops to zero? It seems to decrease steadily so far, so I suppose it is some kind of countdown to a bad outcome...

Any information would help, thanks!

Comment: Okay it is not hunger or sugar level, I ate a chocolate bar and it didn't increase it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The game features four different gauges, for warmth, tiredness, nutrition and hydratation. When either of those gauges is empty, an icon (which is also depicted above the leftmost extremity of the relevant gauge - that's how I found that answer) is displayed in the bottom-left corner of the screen, along with a percentage. As long as the character suffers deprivation from the relevant need, that percentage decreases with time.

At ten percent, the game starts reflecting the effects of the deprivation, and the percentage turns red. As the percentage gets lower, the displayed effects worsen. If this percentage reaches zero, the character dies.

The significance of this specific icon is that the character has reached a frozen state, due to his (or her) low body temperature.